# Matlab/Python like linspace in C

Tags: python, c, matlab

I'm trying to translate the code for an application from MATLAB to C, to improve performance. For this I need to write helper-functions which can generate equally spaced vectors like linspace does, from matlab; https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265
#define DEG2RAD PI / 180
#define DIMS 3

typedef struct Model {

  double radius;

} model;


void BUILD_MODEL(struct Model model);
void LINSPACE(double, double, const int, double []);

int main(){
  struct Model model;

  model.radius = 5e-3; 

  BUILD_MODEL(model);
  return 0;
}

void LINSPACE(double start, double end, const int steps, double vector[steps]){
  double diff;
  double step_length;
  diff = start - end;
  printf("Diff: %d\n", diff);
  step_length = diff/steps;
  printf("step length: %d\n", step_length);
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<steps;i++){
    vector[i] = start + i*step_length;
  };
}

void BUILD_MODEL(struct Model model){
  printf("Building model...\n");
  double linspace_x[11], linspace_y[11], linspace_z[11];

  LINSPACE(-model.radius,model.radius, 11, linspace_x);
  LINSPACE(-model.radius,model.radius, 11, linspace_y);

  printf("%d\n", linspace_x[0]);
  printf("%d\n", linspace_y[0]);
}
```

Print outs when I run the output `.exe` file become;

```
Building model...
Diff: 1202590843
step length: -593486390
Diff: 1202590843
step length: -593486390
1202590843
1202590843
```

What I expected:

```
Building model...
Diff: 0.01
step length: 0.00091
Diff: 0.01
step length: 0.00091
-0.005
-0.005
```

Any takers?

Comment: `%d` is an integer format specifier. Use `%f`.

Comment: Okay, that worked... I thought I had tried that already but appearently not. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I would try and get rid of for loops in your Matlab code first and do vector-based calculations. The speed should be pretty close to C or actually faster than hand-written C code.

Comment: Or, if you want to beat Matlab, check out the numerical libraries that are optimized for your processor by multiple generations of senior programmers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries

Comment: if you have the MATLAB code, why not using the MATLAB Coder to create C code automatically?

Comment: Thank you for these replies, I'll consider them.